# How to make progress bar work on multiple checkbox checked?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have made a progress bar increment on checkbox checked. It works fine with single group of checkboxes but with multiple group of checkboxes it does not work as aspected.

**What I want**

I want if I use multiple card and in each card there would be multiple checkbox they all should work seperatly

```js
$('.card').each(function(index, el) {
  // console.log( $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').length );
  var chkLength = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
  var max = 100;
  var div = max / chkLength;

  $('.scrumboard .card .task-quantity').text('0/' + chkLength);

  // $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').append("<div>" + div +" </div>");
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('value', div);
});

// Progress bar code
val = 0;
$('.card .new-control-input').on('change', function(event) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log('chk');
    // perc += parseInt($(this).val());
    // $(this).attr('checked', '');
    console.log(val += parseInt($(this).val()));
  } else {
    console.log('nchk');
    console.log(val -= parseInt($(this).val()));
  }

  $(".progress .progress-bar").each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).css("width", val + "%");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="task-quantity"></p>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bgbbg-primary" role="progressbar" style="" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="task-quantity"></p>
</div>
```

Link

Comment: Please add some of Your code and what are the expectation vs what is it doing now?

Comment: Grant me some time

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Update the question

Comment: Thank you for editing. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're updating *all* the `.progress .progress-bar` elements in the DOM when the checkbox `change` event fires. You instead need to use DOM traversal to find the progress bar related to the checkbox which raised the event. To achieve this you can use `closest()` to get the parent `.card`, then `find()`.

You will also need to maintain each `width` individually, instead of the shared `val` variable. To do this you can use a `data` attribute which is stored directly on the progress bar. Try this:

```js
$('.card').each(function(index, el) {
  var chkLength = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
  var max = 100;
  var div = max / chkLength;
  $('.scrumboard .card .task-quantity').text('0/' + chkLength);
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('value', div);
});

$('.card .new-control-input').on('change', function(event) {
  var $checkbox = $(this);

  $checkbox.closest('.card').find(".progress .progress-bar").css("width", function() {
    var width = $(this).data('width') || 0;
    if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      width += parseInt($checkbox.val());
    } else {
      width -= parseInt($checkbox.val());
    }
    $(this).data('width', width);
    return width + "%";
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="task-quantity"></p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bgbbg-primary" role="progressbar" style="" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="task-quantity"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your snippet is not working as It should. Try to check the second  progress bar

Comment: Its great and working. But how can we pass a variable from our preferred language to javascript. For eg: I'm working in ruby, I ve an instance variable that contain a value from DB, how to access this variable in javascript method.     @Rory McCrossan

Comment: If the JS code is placed somewhere the Ruby will be interpreted (ie. NOT in a JS file, then you can output the Ruby value as you normally would, eg: `var myJSVariable = '<%= myRubyVariable %>';`

Comment: Okay, but in my case it is not working, getting as string. So we can use it like Inside the html add a hidden field 

   <%= hidden_field_tag :milestone_count, @milestones_count %>

After that call that in javascript file to get the ruby variable
 
  alert($("#milestone_count").val());

Comment: In that case you should start a new question about it, as unfortunately I know nothing about Ruby.